# ios AFDownloadRequestOperation i use it, why after start the Interface no response

Tags: ios, performance, file, download, operation

Please help me, why i start AFDownloadRequestOperation , the interface no response, but i downloaded the file , the interface response.How should I solve it?

I think is it concerned with the write speed of file, download too fast and write too fast if you can keep the program with no response?

this is my code:

```
self.operation = [[AFDownloadRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:[[NSURLRequest      
                                alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:video.url]] 
                                                          targetPath:[[[[PlistManager         
                                           sharedInstance] getDirectory]  
                                        stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString  
                               stringWithFormat:@"%@.mp4",video.vid]] 
                                                        shouldResume:YES];

[self.operation start];
```

Comment: Please add some code. It's unlikely the write speed, and more likely you're sending a synchronous request.

Comment: thx,the code in above. i need another action?

Comment: i use the project https://github.com/steipete/AFDownloadRequestOperation

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you're telling the operation to start on your main thread. This will block your UI.

You want to create and retain a `NSOperationQueue` and add your operation to that, so it executes in the background.

Alternatively, `AFHTTPClient` also creates and maintains an operation queue, so if you already have one of those, you can add your operation to its operation queue.

Comment: thanks,MishieMoo. i found the problem, because i want to write the progress to the file, but it is on the main thread. so i use dispatch_async to solve the problem. but uitableview scroll not smooth in downloading video? my device is iPhone 4